# How to call method outside the innerClass using super keyword

Tags: java

How do I call a method outside the innerClass? I did the extends method but it told me that the method Attributes is undefined even though I did extends, is it because I can't extend a class inside a class?

Here's my code:

```
package mainClass;

import java.util.Random;
import mainClass.Characters;
import mainClass.Main;

class Characters {
  
  static String name = "";
  static int attack = 0;
  static int maxAttack = 0;
  static int hp = 0;
  static int def = 0;
  
  static class Selena extends Attributes {
    
    private static void main() {
      
      super.Attributes();
      //I extend Attributes but why does he not recognize the class Attributes
      
    }
    
    public static void Scratch() {
      
      System.out.println(" uses Scratch!");
      
    }
    
  }
  
  
  static class Attributes {
    
    Attributes() {
      
      
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: There is a lot that looks really weird in the code. You seem to be adding the "static" keyword everywhere and i suspect you aren't fully aware what it does. You are trying to call "super" in the static main method which makes no sense. All your inner classes are declared as static as well, which means they behave just like normal top level classes. Overall i would recommend maybe not trying to do anything with inner classes and work on learning the basics of the java language.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree with OH GOD SPIDERS. I think the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) are a good start to study the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super.x()` is a way to invoke **methods** from your parent class.

`Attributes` is **not a method**. In fact, that `Attributes() {}` at the very end of your paste isn't a method either; it's a constructor.

If you want to make a new Attributes object, you use the `new` keyword, and `super` is right out - you can't use `super` to invoke such things. But you don't have to - just `new Attributes();` will do it, because super has **only one purpose** - that is to differentiate the call to the method in your own class vs. the version you overrode. Thus:

```
class Parent {
    void hello() {
        System.out.println("From parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void foo() {
        hello();
    }
}
```

Note how in the above example there is no `super.` and yet that will work fine, and the call to `hello()` would print `"From parent"`. But:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    void hello() {
        // this overrides
        System.out.println("From child");
    }

    void foo() {
        hello(); // prints 'from child'
        super.hello(); // prints 'from parent'
    }
}
```

Furthermore, `super.x()` is only valid in the class itself and not any inner class thereof, which fortunately doesn't matter for your case.

NB: `super` is used for three mostly to completely unrelated java features. Generics contravariant bounds (this is completely unrelated to what you're doing, so I won't delve into it further), invoking the parent class implementation of methods, and picking which constructor of parent to run first. That last one may be what you want, but that is only valid in constructors themselves, and `main` is not a constructor:

```
class MyAttrs extends Attributes {
    public MyAttrs(String x) {
        super(x);
    }
}

class Attributes {
    public Attributes(String x) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Both of the looks-like-a-method thingies are constructors; You *MUST* invoke exactly one of your parent constructors, OR one of your own, as first thing in any constructor. If you fail to do so, java acts as if `super();` is at the top of your method. You can use `super(argsHere)` to explicitly choose one of the constructors of your parent class to invoke.